# How to set a File in a React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using the React FilePicker tool which requires a "handFileChange" method. In that method, I'm trying to set my a file variable in my react state to the file that's used as a parameter for the method.

I'm trying to also implement a getter method that will return the current file. However, when I go to console.log the file from the getter method, I get a blank line

Any suggestions? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` is not synchronous, use its callback instead

```
setState(
  { file: [file] },
  () => console.log(this.state.file)
);
```

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component...

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

With the official documentation of React : https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

You must use function callback here :

```
setState(stateChange[, callback])
```

Example :

```
setState({file: [file]}, () => { console.log(this.state.file) });
```

Moreover, if you want to debug and watch the state and prop of component. I recommend you using React Developer Tool. It help so much easier https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi